# PySpark: Make a column of positive numbers negative

Tags: pyspark

Pretty straightforward. I have a PySpark dataframe with a column of positive numbers I'd like to make negative. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use df.withColumn attribute
To change a column name 'original'

```
df = df.withColumn('flipped', - df['orginal'])
```

This adds a new column under the name flipped with the needed result. To just change the sign on that column name you can do

```
df = df.withColumn('original', - df['orginal'])
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: Why would just accessing it as df[original] flip the value?

Comment: `flipped` is the name of your column you are creating and the resulting column will be just a copy of `original` column.

Comment: Sorry. missing sign.